# Passing parameters to strftime method

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python. my question is how to pass parameter to date.strftime() or a workaround
Below is the code

```
from datetime import date
dl_date = date.today()
p = '%d%b%Y' # the format may vary %d%B%Y or %d%m%Y or % d%M%Y etc
file_date_format = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(str(dl_date.strftime('%r')),str(dl_date.strftime('%r').upper())
                                       , str(dl_date.strftime('%r'))) % (p[:2], p[2:4], p[4:6])
print(file_date_format)
```

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean *"how to pass parameter"*? It's an instance method, you can call `dl_date.strftime(p)`.

Comment: Are you trying to use `%` to put p[:2], p[2:4], and p[4:6] in place of each `%r` in your three calls to strftime? That seems quite elaborate. What is this code supposed to actually do?

Answer (score 0):

No need to use percent style string formatting here. Just stick the p slices directly in the `strftime` calls.

```
from datetime import date
dl_date = date.today()
p = '%d%b%Y' # the format may vary %d%B%Y or %d%m%Y or % d%M%Y etc
file_date_format = "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(
    str(dl_date.strftime(p[:2])),
    str(dl_date.strftime(p[2:4]).upper()), 
    str(dl_date.strftime(p[4:6]))
)
print(file_date_format)
```

Result:

```
14/NOV/2014
```

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that, want to know if we can pass parameters

Comment: I _am_ passing parameters here. Maybe we are using different meanings. What does "pass parameters" mean to you?

Comment: I mean strftime(%s or %r)  instead of strftime(p[:] )

Comment: You could do `strftime("%s" % p[:2])`, but it wouldn't be very useful. If you're asking whether you can put the percent operator and formatting tuple outside of the parentheses, far away from the actual string: no, you can't.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking if i could put the formatting tuple outside of the parentheses.